# Getting per-category counts of list items with jq

Tags: json, shell, jq, categorization

I'm currently learning how to use jq with shell in Linux since I'm developing custom checks for Check_MK (formerly known as Nagios) and my application (qBittorrent with their [WebUI API](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/WebUI-API-Documentation)) returns JSON strings.

Currently, I'm already able to count the total number of torrents just by using a simple `jq length`. Now, I would like to count the number of torrents that are currently dowloading, seeding or on pause. I'm only interested by the `state`, so if I have 6 torrents, my JSON could look like that:

```
[
  {
    "state": "uploading"
  },
  {
    "state": "downloading"
  },
  {
    "state": "downloading"
  },
  {
    "state": "downloading"
  },
  {
    "state": "pauseDL"
  },
  {
    "state": "pauseUP"
  }
]
```

Here, `jq length` returns 6. What do I need to do to get the details such as 3 are downloading, 1 is uploading, 2 are paused and 0 are in error?

Here is my actual script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
curl -s http://localhost:8080/query/torrents -o /tmp/torrents.json
count=$(jq length /tmp/torrents.json)
echo "0 qbt_Nb_torrents - $count"
```

The syntax for the `echo` is required by Check_MK (as explained [here](https://mathias-kettner.com/cms_localchecks.html#syntax)).

I've read multiple examples on filters but they all seem to be working when we're filtering through the top-level attributes. Here, my top level is basically just [0], ..., [5], so it doesn't work with the examples I've found in the manual.

**Additional information**

The WebUI API says there are 12 different possible states. That's how I intend to split them up:

```
downloading: queuedDL, checkingDL, downloading 
uploading: queuedUP, checkingUP, uploading 
pause: pausedUP, pausedDL 
error: error 
stalled: stalledUP, stalledDL, metaDL
```

As per the CheckMK syntax, I need to basically output something like:

> 0 qbt_Nb_torrents - 6 total, 3 downloading, 1 seeding, 2 on pause, 0 stalled, 0 error

The first 0 at the beginning means an OK status for CheckMK. If there are any stalled torrents, I want that status to become 1, and if there is any torrent in error, the status becomes 2. Example:

> 2 qbt_Nb_torrents - 8 total, 3 downloading, 1 seeding, 2 on pause, 1 stalled, 1 error

Comment: No need for a temporary file, btw. `curl | jq` will work perfectly well, as will `s=$(curl ...)`, and then `jq ... <<<"$s"` (though you'll need to switch from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` for the latter).

Comment: (Temporary files create security risks when neither in a private location unwritable by other users, nor created with `mktemp` or other tools which generate a random, unique name; someone who runs `ln -s /etc/passwd /tmp/torrents.json` before your script is invoked could cause it to overwrite `/etc/passwd` when run as root, even if they themselves only had permission to write to `/tmp`).

Comment: BTW, your stated desired output includes a "seeding" state, but that's not in your list of the possible states from the API.

Comment: Also, your sample data has `pauseDL`, but your statement about possible API states has `pausedDL`, with an extra `d`.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @CharlesDuffy. I use a temporary file because I actually gather more information from that curl, I have multiple checks and this is just being one of them. Also note that this VM is only accessible from my local network with no ports forwarded from my router.

Comment: I fixed the paused states, thank you. As for seeding, it's basically uploading written differently, a seeding torrent is not a torrent that is currently downloading, sometimes using "uploading" can be a little bit more confusing. Either way, I managed to make my categories work with if/elif with your provided filterStates, the only thing I haven't got working yet is outputting everything in a 1-liner rather than 5 rows.

Comment: See edited answer for a filterStates definition that might make more sense given the API spec added to the edited question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Definitely a better approach than what I had initially. I edited only to add the seeding part to the output, it works as is.

Comment: ...just realized I'd left out the "total". (And btw, as a point of clarity: Please *don't* take this level of attention to requirements beyond a narrow and specific question as appropriate to the site; I'm going beyond what the rules call for -- and maybe even harming the knowledgebase's usefulness, making the answer less useful to people who aren't you, by diverting focus from the grouped-counts narrow, immediate question -- because you managed to come up with a problem that's a somewhat fun exercise to answer).

Comment: The end up result is very nice too, trust me. It's just a home-server using unRAID, since I'm hosting some services that can be used by others such as a TeamSpeak server VM or a Python Discord bot, I decided to host a little CheckMK VM to receive emails when things go wrong. It's a very fun personal project where I get to learn so much about so many different things it's crazy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added my end result as another answer just for extra references if anyone comes here while searching specifically about either qBittorrent Web API or how to make Check_MK custom checks. Anyone coming here for `jq` can go through your edits like you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*For others with related questions, but not sharing the OP's specific requirements: See edit history! There are several other relevant proposals, including `group_by` use, in prior iterations of this answer.*

---

If you need entries for *all* values, even ones which have no occurrence, you might consider:

```sh
jq -r '
  def filterStates($stateMap):
    if $stateMap[.] then $stateMap[.] else . end;

  def errorLevel:
    if (.["error"] > 0) then 2 else
      if (.["stalled"] > 0) then 1 else
        0
      end
    end;

  {"queuedDL": "downloading", 
   "checkingDL": "downloading",
   "queuedUP": "uploading", 
   "checkingUP": "uploading",
   "pausedUP": "pause", 
   "pausedDL": "pause",
   "stalledUP": "stalled", 
   "stalledDL": "stalled", 
   "metaDL": "stalled"} as $stateMap |

  # initialize an output array since we want 0 outputs for everything
  {"pause": 0,  "stalled": 0, "error": 0, "downloading": 0, "uploading": 0} as $counts |

  # count number of items which filter to each value
  reduce (.[].state | filterStates($stateMap)) as $state ($counts; .[$state]+=1) |

  # actually format an output string
  "\(. | errorLevel) qbt_Nb_torrents - \(values | add) total, \(.["downloading"]) downloading, \(.["uploading"]) seeding, \(.["pause"]) on pause, \(.["stalled"]) stalled, \(.["error"]) error"
' /tmp/torrents.json
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested multiple of you edits and they all work one way or another. I will need to adapt since I still need the 0 outputs if there are 0 torrents on pause for example to prevent Check_MK check from crashing but it's pretty simple to do from there (I can just set default values first basically).

Comment: Pays to be explicit about all your requirements up-front; if I'd known that was what you needed, I probably would have stuck with and expanded the reducer approach.

Comment: Yes, according to the linked documentation of the WebUI API, there are 12 different states. I will definitely regroup them into just 4 or 5 categories, basically downloading, seeding, on pause or error. That latest state will trigger a critical warning in CheckMK (so instead of being 0, the status will be 3 as per CheckMK linked documentation). Besides, I will probably have it return everything in 1 row, like `0 qbt_Nb_torrents - 6 total, 3 downloading, 1 seeding, 2 on pause, 0 in error`.

Comment: Well -- after you have a correct answer is the wrong time to change the requirements; that generally gets us into "ask a new question" territory. See the discussion of "chameleon questions" at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal on [meta].

Comment: I don't mind posting a new question with the additional info, although it would be almost close enough to be a duplicate. But I will work with your answer first and see where it gets me. Either way, I added the details and accepted your answer.

Comment: Right -- you'd want to focus the new question only on the content not covered in the answer here (ie. the place where you get stuck when working from this one) to avoid being a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more modularized version of @CharlesDuffy's solution. The main point of interest is perhaps the generic "bag of words" filter:

```
# bag of words
def bow(init; s): reduce s as $word (init; .[$word] += 1) ;
```

Note also the initialization function:

```
# initialize an output object since we minimally want 0s
def init:
  {} | {pause,stalled,error,downloading,uploading} | map_values(0);
```

With these additional abstractions, the "main" program becomes just two lines of code.

```
  def filterStates($stateMap):
    if $stateMap[.] then $stateMap[.] else . end ;

  def errorLevel:
    if .error > 0 then 2
    elif .stalled > 0 then 1
    else 0
    end ;

  def stateMap:
    {"queuedDL": "downloading", 
     "checkingDL": "downloading",
     "queuedUP": "uploading", 
     "checkingUP": "uploading",
     "pausedUP": "pause", 
     "pausedDL": "pause",
     "stalledUP": "stalled", 
     "stalledDL": "stalled", 
     "metaDL": "stalled"} ;
```

### "Main"

```
  # count number of items which map to each value
  bow(init; .[].state | filterStates(stateMap))
  # format an output string
  | "\(errorLevel) qbt_Nb_torrents - \(values | add) total, \(.downloading) downloading, \(.uploading) seeding, \(.pause) on pause, \(.stalled) stalled, \(.error) error"
```

Comment: So you don't use `jq` at all or is it implicit in your example?

Comment: Only the jq program (aka filter) is shown. (Obviously?)

Comment: Just tested it, it does work. It basically saves 2-3 rows of code. Considering the checks are run every 60 sec and Check_MK can execute hundreds of checks at the same time, I'm wondering if it makes a difference in terms of performances.

Comment: The main difference comes from the use of bow().

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is wondering what I exactly ended up using following Charles Duffy's excellent answer, here is the full `/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local/qbittorrent` shell script that allows Check_MK (1.5.0 raw) to get what I think is the most relevant information about my qBittorrent application (qBittorrent v3.3.7 Web UI) running in a dedicated VM on my server:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
curl -s http://localhost:8080/query/transferInfo -o /tmp/transferInfo.json
curl -s http://localhost:8080/query/torrents -o /tmp/torrents.json

if [ -e /tmp/transferInfo.json ]
then
 dwl=$(jq .dl_info_speed /tmp/transferInfo.json)
 dwl_MB=$(bc <<< "scale=2;$dwl/1048576")
 upl=$(jq .up_info_speed /tmp/transferInfo.json)
 upl_MB=$(bc <<< "scale=2;$upl/1048576")
 echo "0 qbt_Global_speed download=$dwl_MB|upload=$upl_MB Download: $dwl_MB MB/s, Upload: $upl_MB MB/s"
 rm -f /tmp/transferInfo.json
else
 echo "3 qbt_Global_speed download=0|upload=0 Can't get the information from qBittorrent WebUI API"
fi

if [ -e /tmp/torrents.json ]
then    
 jq -r '
   def filterStates($stateMap):
    if $stateMap[.] then $stateMap[.] else . end;

   {"queuedDL": "downloading",
   "checkingDL": "downloading",
   "queuedUP": "uploading",
   "checkingUP": "uploading",
   "pausedUP": "pause",
   "pausedDL": "pause",
   "stalledUP": "stalled",
   "stalledDL": "stalled",
   "metaDL": "stalled"} as $stateMap |

   # initialize an output array since we want 0 outputs for everything
   {"pause": 0,  "stalled": 0, "error": 0, "downloading": 0, "uploading": 0} as $counts |

   # count number of items which filter to each value
   reduce (.[].state | filterStates($stateMap)) as $state ($counts; .[$state]+=1) |

   # output string
   "P qbt_Nb_torrents total=\(values|add)|downloading=\(.["downloading"])|seeding=\(.["uploading"])|pause=\(.["pause"])|stalled=\(.["stalled"]);0|error=\(.["error"]);0;0 total is \(values|add), downloading is \(.["downloading"]), seeding is \(.["uploading"]), pause is \(.["pause"])"
' /tmp/torrents.json

 rm -f /tmp/torrents.json
else
 echo "3 qbt_Nb_torrents total=0|downloading=0|seeding=0|pause=0|stalled=0;0|error=0;0;0 Can't get the information from qBittorrent WebUI API"
fi
```

Here is the output with 1 stalled torrent:

```
0 qbt_Global_speed download=0|upload=0 Download: 0 MB/s, Upload: 0 MB/s
P qbt_Nb_torrents total=1|downloading=0|seeding=0|pause=0|stalled=1;0|error=0;0;0 total is 1, downloading is 0, seeding is 0, pause is 0
```

The `errorLevel` that I thought I needed (see Charles's answer) isn't required because of how Check_MK works; it handles the thresholds itself through [the metric parameter](https://mathias-kettner.com/cms_localchecks.html#perfdata) when warning and critical values are specified.

Here is what it looks like in Check_MK:

[image: Check_MK view]

Notice how Check_MK automatically added stalled and errored torrents. This is because of the warning and/or critical thresholds being specified. The metrics in general (with or without thresholds) are important to have the detailed relevant charts available.